# Структура проекта. Сортировка классов на package, namespases, folders

Tags: java, android, c#, архитектура, шаблоны

Как правильно раскидывать классы на `папки` и `namespace` в VS и `package` в Java? 
 То есть, другими словами, рекомендации по организации структуры проекта. 
Какие вообще есть стандартные папки (Часто встречал `core, utils, support, additionals`, etc...)
И есть ли какие стандартные правила/рекомендации для разбиения.
Если нет, то хотя бы общее описание этих папок/пакетов.
Вопрос и для Java, и Java под android, и C#, если между ними в этом есть различия.

Comment: для удобства если только)

Comment: Нет никаких стандартов, есть то, к чему пприходят разные разработчики по разному, никто Вас организации исходников не научит.

Answer (score 4):

В C#, как правило, структура папок повторяет namespace классов, которые содержаться в этих папках. Solutions (.sln) содержат обыкновенно src папку с кодом.

Пример сложного проекта можно посмотреть в исходниках [CoreFx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx). Для проектов поменьше, обычно делают только один solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. .NET
   VisualStudio по-умолчанию предлагает следующий вариант:

   - Solution состоит из одного или более проектов
   - Корневой `namespase` проекта совпадает с именем проекта, это поведение можно изменить в свойствах проекта.
   - Если в проекте есть вложенные папки, то в новых файлах классов к корневому `namespase` добавляются вложенные, с именами совпадающими с именами папок.
   - Никаких ограничений на расположение и количество классов в файлах нет, за исключением одного - если класс содержит метод `Main`, то этот класс должен быть первым в файле чтобы его можно было запустить, во всяком случае студия на этом настаивает, обходить это ограничение не пробовал, не знаю.

Стандартные папки проекта можно посмотреть создав проект в студии и изучив содержимое папки проекта, большинство из них служебные и не будут отображаться в обозревателе решений.

Поведение студии по-умолчанию является всего лишь предлагаемым вариантом, следовать которому не обязательно. Все на усмотрение команды разработки и стандартов кода в компании.

2. Java

   - Из моего, довольно поверхностного, знакомства с java удалось выяснить следующее:
   - Имя файла и класса в нем обязаны совпадать
   - Один файл - один класс, за исключением вложенных классов разумеется (возможно что это не обязательно, не пробовал)
   - Package (пакет) - фактически является папкой, т.е. структура папок и задает структуру пакетов

По поводу Java могу местами ошибаться, т.к. повторюсь, не слишком много с ней работал, и не в курсе последних изменений.

У Java, насколько я понимаю, как таковых стандартных папок нет, хотя, можно проделать такой же трюк как с VS в используемой вами IDE для Java.

Если вы имели ввиду стандартные названия для папок с исходным кодом, то это определяется командой разработки и/или стандартами кода компании.

Comment: Да, имел в виду рекомендации по названию папок/примеры стандартных папок и разбиению классов по ним

Comment: @АлексейСтепанов как уже писали в комментариях - нет таких рекомендаций, единственная рекомендация - структура папок должна быть понятной для всех членов команды, поэтому и определять эти названия должна команда. Ну или вы сами, если работаете соло.

Comment: @АлексейСтепанов возможно немного особняком будут стоять ASP.NET и ASP.NET-MVC проекты, но это лучше уточнить в документации или литературе по данным технологиям и типам проектов.