# Существуют ли стандартные положения по оформлению проектов?

Tags: java, книги, юнит-тесты

Существует какая-то литература или сводка правил по оформлению, не в плане грамотного кода, а проекта  в целом (обязательны ли разного вида тесты при компиляции, есть ли стандартные правила по "правильному" строению структуры пакетов и наименования оных и т. д.), или все берётся чисто из практики/наблюдений/личных соображений?

Comment: Единственное общее правило состоит в том, что классы, которые связаны друг с другом, лежат близко в пакетах. (Но никто не мешает вам свалить все классы в один пакет)

Comment: см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521795